# Bilinear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, continuity

The question is as follows, and I have added my attempt at the proof, but I don't have much information about bilinear mappings. Rudin only provided a definition. I was hoping that you all might be able to help me out. I'm just not sure about my argument. Any help or critiques are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Let $X$ be the normed space of all real polynomials in one variable, with 
$$
\|f\| = \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt.
$$
Put, $B(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t) dt,$ and show that $B$ is a bilenear functional on $ X \times X$ which is seperately continuous but is not continuous.

proof:

Let $X$ be the normed space of all real polynomials in one variable, with
$$
\|f\| = \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt. 
$$
Let $B(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt.$ Then let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \mu \in \Phi$

\begin{eqnarray*}
B(\alpha f + \beta g, \gamma h + \mu k) &=& \int_0^1 (\alpha f(t) + \beta g(t))(\gamma h(t) + \mu k(t)) dt \\
&=& \int_0^1 \alpha f(t) (\gamma h(t) + \mu k(t)) + \beta g(t) (\gamma h(t) + \mu k(t))dt \\
&=& \alpha \gamma \int_0^1 f(t) h(t) dt + \alpha \mu \int_0^1 f(t)k(t) dt \\
&& \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+ \beta \gamma \int_0^1 g(t) h(t) dt + \beta \mu \int_0^1 g(t) k(t) dt \\
&=& \alpha \gamma B(f,h) + \alpha \mu B(f,k) + \beta \gamma B(g,h) + \beta \mu B(g,k).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $B(f,g)$ is bilinear. (Not sure if this is a proper argument).

It suffices to show that $B(f,g)$ is seperately continuous if $B_x(f)$ and $B^y(f)$ are continuous at the origin. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions such that $\{f_n\} \rightarrow 0$. Then $B_x(f_n) \rightarrow B_x(0) \rightarrow 0$ since we have $B_x$ linear, hence $B_x$ is continuous. The same will be true for the continuity of $B^y(f)$. (I'm not really sure how to talk about $B_x$ or $B^y$ individually other than this type of argument.)

To show that $B(f,g)$ is not continuous. Consider the the following sequences of functions $f_n(t) = \sqrt{n}t^n$. Then we have, 
$$
\|f_n\| = \int_0^1 \sqrt{n} t^n dt = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}(1)^{n+1} \rightarrow 0.
$$
However, 
$$
B(f_n,f_n) = \int_0^1 (\sqrt{n} t^n)(\sqrt{n} t^n) dt = \int_0^1 n t^{2n} dt = \frac{n}{2n+1}(1)^{2n+1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}. 
$$
Hence $B(f,g)$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your argument is proper, for bilinearity, especially in a *symmetric* case like this one, it is enough to verify
$$B(\alpha f+ g,\,h)=\alpha\, B(f,h)+B(g,h)\,.$$

In an *infinite dimensional* space (as the space of all real polynomials), linearity doesn't imply continuity, so you should prove it in a similar way as you gave the counterexample.

Say, $g$ is fixed and $\|f_n\|\to 0$. Use $G:=\max_{x\in [0,1]} |g(x)|$ to show $B(f_n,g)\to 0$.

Comment: So, if I am understanding this correctly by fixing the function g we are able to say that $B_x(f) = B(f,g)$. Also, would it be redundant to show $B(\alpha f + \beta g, h) = \alpha B(f,h) + \beta B(g,h)$.

Comment: Well, a bit redundant, but that also works. And you have to mention commutativity of $B$ for the general statement.
Actually, that subscript '$x$' in $B_x(f)$ wants to mean $B(x,f)$, no? If so, then $B(f,g)=B^g(f)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity of the notation. I have 4 other functional analysis text for other reference materials but non of them seem to mention Bilinear mappings. As you have stated this makes much more since.